# Remote MSMQ connection performance

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue, msmq

We experience a lack of performance during iteration across remote private MSMQ queue. We tried to use both API methods - MessageQueue.GetAllMessages() and MessageQueue.GetEnumerator2() and see the same results.

It seems that the problem is in Message Queuing Service, because it always uses only up to 15% of CPU (single core). For example, if we iterate across local queue - we use 100% of CPU and can load 1 million messages in 2 seconds, but for remote queues it takes 30 seconds to load only 10K! Network connection is 100MBPs.

**Is there a way to increase MSMQ performance for remote queues and force it to use 100% of CPU or Network?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSMQ is optimised to go as fast as it can - it's not going slow just to irritate you.

Performance will be poor on remote queues. This is not the best way to use MSMQ. High performance is obtained through the "send remote, read local" model.

Remote access uses RPC which will be slow over a LAN. If you looked at a network trace, you would see all the back-and-forth communication. Binding to the remote RPC service and querying to find where MSMQ is listening; binding to the remote MSMQ RPC listener; requesting messages from the listener; etc etc.

Comment: I understand that it is not a typical task and in 99% cases fast remote peek is not required. We are developing the MSMQ viewer application. I also understand that "it's not going slow just to irritate you" and I posted this question to be sure that there is no way to make it as fast as local queues. I am confused why Message Queuing Service do not use all available PC resources - if the problem in RPC performance then why it does not load Network? Or may be it just send messages one by one using TCP and waits for receive acknowledgment for every message.

Comment: maybe there are some tips or tricks how to configure the request, so that RPC footprint would be minimized ?

Comment: The requesting machine has to wait for the queue host to process and respond to the chain of RPC requests. The requester also has to process the responses. The network adds an overhead in each direction and that all adds up.  I strongly recommend running a network trace so you see how long just one message takes to read.

Comment: "Or may be it just send messages one by one using TCP and waits for receive acknowledgment for every message." No, you are not sending messages - that uses the MSMQ protocol. You are reaching out and pulling a message back from a remote queue over RPC. Completely different mechanism.

Comment: "Maybe there are some tips or tricks how to configure the request, so that RPC footprint would be minimized?" MSMQ crafts the request. The app just says "give me stuff". Tip #1 - don't receive messages from remote queues. Tip #2 - don't search for stuff. If there are 1,000s of messages and you are peeking each in turn to find a particular message then you will die of old age.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be relevant in your scenario, but it's a way to improve overall performance for MSMQ.

If you're sending messages that wrap a consistent type - a serialized class, for example - buffer them before sending and send one message containing an array or collection of items.

I was working with some serialized class and sending a large volume of messages. I tested and found that if I sent them in batches of 50 instead of individually then the size of queue was reduced by 75%. I didn't spend much time optimizing from there. It depends on the size of your messages. But this gets rid of much of the overhead incurred in sending individual messages.

Comment: This optimization could defeat the reason you are using the queue in that an unexpected failure would loose the cached messages that have not been written yet.

Comment: True. I flush the buffer every few seconds whether it's full or not. But you're right. A message is safer in the queue than in the buffer. The resulting risk is very small for my application, but it might be unacceptable for another application. In my case it was website usage stats, so if the application stopped so abruptly that it couldn't flush then I risked losing a handful of messages out of millions.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Our question though is about reading messages with a purpose of displaying them in a grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the TCP connection syntax and use an explicit numerical IP address  123.123.123.123.   See if this affects your performance.  If it does then think security.

You use the terms GetMessage but also talk about loading so I am confused about if you want performance on Message Receive “GetOne” or Load into the queue operations.

For core production code I always operate one at a time on the messages so I am never trying to GetAllMessages or EnumerateAllMessages except in specific management functions.

Comment: Our goal is to peek (without removing) all messages from private queue. We are developing the MSMQ viewer application. Unfortunately, explicit IP does not help.